# EditText problem

Tags: android

I want to get a character of a string from a EditText and at the same time want to show the current location's latitude and longitude.

here shown a part of the code

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.format);


 btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

                showCurrentLocation();
        }
        });

protected void showCurrentLocation() {

         text=name.getText().toString();

         String finalText = "";
         finalText = Character.toString(text.charAt(3));

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
                String message = String.format(
                                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
                );
                Toast.makeText(GPSLocator.this, message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

After compiling the code when i give any character and click on the sent button then a message is displayed on the screen like "The application GPSLocator(process com.vetexVervelnc GPSLocator) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again   Forse close  "

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
 finalText = ""+text.charAt(3);
```

Make sure you put correct permission in manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the exact error you get?

The following code may be of assistance.

```
try{
    finalText = Character.toString(text.charAt(3));
    } catch {Exception e) {
    finalText="";
}
```